# Is there a pool that will tell you the real time shares you've submitted?

Tags: mining-pools, cpu-mining, mining-theory, difficulty-share

I'm trying some mining on my MacBook Pro.  Although I don't expect to make any money, I was curious if the software I'm using is actually submitting the shares it is reporting.  Is there a pool that will tell you in (basically) real time how many shares you've successfully submitted?  I have been using https://mixpools.org/xmr/, but since its minimum payout is 0.2 XMR, there's no way to tell if I'm successfully submitting shares until I get a payout (which would require a few billion successful share submissions I'm guessing).

Answer (score 0):

most pools have a "lookup" where you can put in your wallet address and it will show you how many shares you've submitted (after your first share is found usually)

most pools i've seen will show this information even if you haven't reached payout

Comment: Do you have an example of such a pool, maybe one that you have used before?